# Can I make __udivdi3 and __umoddi3 part of the calling function in gprof?

Tags: c, gprof

My program produces this profile:

```
Flat profile:

Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name    
 29.79      0.14     0.14   227764     0.00     0.00  standardize_state
 21.28      0.24     0.10                             __udivdi3
 14.89      0.31     0.07                             __umoddi3
  8.51      0.35     0.04   170971     0.00     0.00  make_negative_child
  6.38      0.38     0.03  8266194     0.00     0.00  mypow
...
```

My cursory googling tells me that `__udivdi3` and `__umoddi3` are generated by `/` and `%`. And yes there is alot of `/` and `%` in my program.

However it's kind of useless in the profile, I would prefer those calls to be listed as part of the calling function.

Is there any way I can do this, or otherwise make gprof more applicable to this scenario.

Comment: I was hoping someone else would answer you first. This is what you can expect with `gprof`. [*I and others use random pausing.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771)